# Steady state solution using time derivatives set to zero

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I asked to get the SS solution for non-linear parabolic PDE system:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial a}{\partial t}&=D \frac{\partial^2 a}{\partial r^2}+f(a,b)\\
\frac{\partial b}{\partial t}&=D \frac{\partial^2 b}{\partial r^2}+g(a,b)
\end{align}$$

using $2$ different ways:

$1)$ PDE time solution and than check the solution when $t = \infty$

$2)$ ODE system that i get when set the time derivatives to zero.
While the solution is stable (depend on the constants), i can find the SS easily using both methods.

When the solution in time does not converge to SS, the ODE still solvable and I got a solution (not the SS solution, because its not exist).

My questions are:

$1)$ How its come that there is solution for the ODE?

$2)$ What is the meaning of this solution?

** edited **
For example, my work dealt with the following problem:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial a}{\partial t}&=D \frac{\partial^2 a}{\partial r^2}+μ_0-ab^2-Ka\\
\frac{\partial b}{\partial t}&=D \frac{\partial^2 b}{\partial r^2}+ab^2+Ka-b\\
-1<r<1
\end{align}$$

The [PDE Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYxkV.jpg) ,and the [ODE Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qr3JX.jpg)

There is no SS solution, but I still got solution from the ODE.

I used finite differences methods for solving the problems.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any work?

Comment: I edited my question and add my work. Thanks.